# Running an application in background

Tags: bash, freebsd, background-process, zsh, background

I have a web app on a freebsd server. An app is a single executable file, with a built-in webserver. My default shell is zsh.

When I'm running it as "./my_website &" and close a connection, it terminates. **However, when I switch to bash** by "/usr/local/bin/bash" and run my website the same way "./my_website &", then exit bash and close a connection, my website keeps working -- exactly what I need.

What's going on here -- **why does it keep running in bash after I close a connection to my server?**

Is it a good practice to run an app in background this way? If not, what's the proper way to run my website so that it won't terminate after I disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

Or you may run it in screen:

```
screen -dm bash -c '/path/to/your/program'
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to turn your app into a system service and add `yourapp_enable="YES"` into /etc/rc.conf to [re]start it automatically. See [Practical rc.d scripting in BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/rc-scripting/index.html) article for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nohup` command

```
nohup ./my_website &
```

It will let your process run after parent process dies/exits regardless of shell.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is you goal. If you need to run this webserver for a short time (development/test), you can use screen/tmux and leave it in open session.

If you want to run this application in production it is better to write startup script. If this application can't demonize them-self you can use [daemon(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=daemon&apropos=0&sektion=8). I recommend to read [Practical rc.d scripting in BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/rc-scripting/index.html), also you can find a lot of examples in the ports tree. To find rc-scripts with daemon you can use command `find /usr/ports/ -depth 4 -name *.in | xargs fgrep -l /usr/sbin/daemon`

Comment: but why does it keep running in bash?

Comment: **If this application can't demonize them-self** --> how can I check this?

Comment: 1. May be bash doesn't kill background jobs on logout. Anyway you application will be killed if it try to write something in stdout/stderr (you can redirect them to /dev/null).

2. Many application have an option to run in background (demonize), check man page (if it exists).